# Visual Studio web project publish not working

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a finished web project ready to publish. It works fine when I run it in Visual Studio. Then I go to publish it. Visual Studio claims the publication was successful, but when I go to the site on IIS it does not work. The published file system doesn't even have the Images folder, and the links to the Scripts and other folders don't work.

To describe what's happening, first I choose Build-->Publish site. I create a publish profile like so:

[image]

Then I publish it as a File System and pick the folder:

[image]

Then I publish it as Release:

[image]

Then I press Publish:

[image]

Here is the output of the publish website by Visual Studio:

------ Build started: Project: LangSite, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
  LangSite -> C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\LangSite_151209\LangSite_151209\bin\LangSite_151209.dll
------ Publish started: Project: LangSite, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
Connecting to C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\LangTestSite...
Transformed Web.config using C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\LangSite_151209\LangSite_151209\Web.Release.config into obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.
Publishing folder /...
Publishing folder Areas...
Publishing folder Areas/HelpPage...
Publishing folder Areas/HelpPage/Views...
Publishing folder Areas/HelpPage/Views/Help...
Publishing folder Areas/HelpPage/Views/Help/DisplayTemplates...
Publishing folder Areas/HelpPage/Views/Shared...
Publishing folder bin...
Publishing folder Content...
Publishing folder fonts...
Publishing folder Scripts...
Publishing folder Views...
Publishing folder Views/Home...
Publishing folder Views/Shared...
Site was published successfully file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/LangTestSite

========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Here is the layout of the file folders in Visual Studio:

[image]

And here is the file structure of the published site. Notice, no Images folder:

[image]

When I try to go to the site, I get a page of broken links:
[image]
[image]

Clearly I am not using the publish web project correctly, but I don't see any different way to do it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are that your images are in the file system, but they are not in your actual project.

You'll want to tell Visual Studio to 'show all files' its one of the icons in the top of the solution explorer. From there you can see the grayed out items show up under the images folder, and right click and "include in project".

Comment: Thanks for telling me about this. I did click 'show all files' and two folders were grayed out: 'bin' and 'obj.' I included them in the project. But 'Images' was not grayed out. So I still don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, the images folder wasn't grayed out but the images were. I now have included them in the project. I don't think that solves the whole problem but solves part of it. Thanks again.

Comment: Okay, I found the other files that were grayed out, so it works on my local server now. Still doesn't work when I publish it to the other server, but that's a different question. Thanks for solving the problem!

Comment: I also encountered this kind of problem where certain files weren't being published. Turned out to be an error in my code causing a heap of files to not compile properly. Hope this helps someone else :)